# Trigger process through PB after approval.

Tags: process

I have set up a paid time off app with two objects: 1) a staff database that houses the leave allowance and 2) leave request form.

Then, I set up an approval process which after approval updates a "status" picklist value in the leave request object to "approved".

Finally, I built a process through PB to trigger when the "status" value changes to "approved" and updates the leave balance in the staff database object.

The leave balance will not update after the record is approved. Is this possible to piggy back off an approval process? Or am I not doing my update records correctly on PB?

I'm limited to point and click, no code...yet.

Comment: Does the field update on the approval process have the "reevaluate workflow rules" checkbox checked? That could be needed to trigger process builder, definitely would be needed to trigger workflows. Then I would double check your entry criteria for process builder.  There are limits on cross object field updates from approval processes, but I don't think that applies to process builder.  Not positive though